# How to validate auth form data in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to build out authentication in Laravel 5.3. For some reason my form data isn't being validated by the register function in the RegisterUsers.php file. When I fill out the form and send it I get 3 errors telling me the 3 fields are required; Like the data isn't even being passed. I'm not using php artisan make:auth or laravel collectives, I maybe I should. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong here? Thanks, in advance.

### register.blade.php

```
@extends('main')
@section('title','Register')
@section('content')
    <form action='{{Auth::routes('auth.register')}}' method='POST'>
        {{ csrf_field() }} 
        <div class='row well'>
            <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='name'>Name</label>
                    <input type='text' id='name' class='form-control'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='email'>Email</label>
                    <input type='text' id='email' class='form-control'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='password'>Password</label>
                    <input type='password' id='password' class='form-control'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='password'>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type='password' id='password' class='form-control'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='pw-remember'>Remember Me</label>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='pw-remember' class='form-control'>
                </div>

                <input type='submit' value='Login' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

### web.php

```
// auth routes
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('auth/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
// Registration routes
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

Route::get('blog/{slug}', ['as' => 'blog.single', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getSingle'])->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
Route::get('blogs', 'BlogController@getIndex');
Route::get('/', 'PageController@getIndex');
Route::get('about', 'PageController@getAbout');
Route::get('contact', 'PageController@getContact');

Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put `name` attribute for `<input/>` tags

```
@extends('main')
@section('title','Register')
@section('content')
    <form action='{{Auth::routes('auth.register')}}' method='POST'>
        {{ csrf_field() }} 
        <div class='row well'>
            <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='name'>Name</label>
                    <input type='text' id='name' name='name' class='form-control'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='email'>Email</label>
                    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' class='form-control'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='password'>Password</label>
                    <input type='password' id='password' name='password' class='form-control'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='password'>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type='password' id='password' name='confirm_password' class='form-control'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='pw-remember'>Remember Me</label>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='pw-remember' class='form-control' name='pw-remember'>
                </div>

                <input type='submit' value='Login' class='btn btn-success btn-block'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: Just realized this while I was waiting for an answer! Wow, I forgot the name in the input, and replaced the for="" with id="" and everything is working fine. Thanks for the answer!